# Issue having a particular SKAction to fire in a sequence

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2, skaction

I'm sure this is a thread issue but I can't figure it out.
I want to make a sprite fade and reappear somewhere else. I can get it working one way, but not the other (see below) The sequence I want is:

```
fade, x, y, z  (all are SKActions)
```

One of my classes provides the implementation details for the warp in animation (adhering to a Warpable protocol I created)

```
protocol Warpable
{
    func warpOutAnimation() -> SKAction
}

//and then elsewhere, in my actual class:
func warpOutAnimation() -> SKAction
    {
      return SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(1.0)
    }
```

So here is my sequence within the game:

```
 myNode.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(1.0), x, y, z]))
```

**This runs perfectly fine. All good.**

Now, if I wanted to instead grab the warp implementation from the class (since this is dynamic from a factory class I have):

```
 myNode.runAction(SKAction.sequence([
(self.currentMonster as! Warpable).warpOutAnimation(), x, y, z]))
```

This sequence does *not* execute the warpOutAnimation (despite it returning an SKAction) but it does fire x, y, z still.

currentMonster is instantiated from a factory based on some context within my game. I have a breakpoint there, and it does indeed hit the protocol's function to fire, but the SKAction isn't run.

Any ideas why this would happen? Even if I put the warp function right above where I'm doing the sequencing it doesn't do anything.  Thanks so much.

Comment: hah see my mistake? I'm using 'fadeInWithDuration' on 'warpOutAnimation' - it should've been fadeOut!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per docs, the [fadeInWithDuration](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/fadeInWithDuration:) action changes the alpha property of the node from its current value to 1.0.

This action has no effect if alpha value of a node is already 1.0, and that is probably your issue.

What you probably want is, to use [fadeOutWithDuration](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/fadeOutWithDuration:), to make a node disappear, before you try to use `fadeInWithDuration` method to make it re-appear.

So, make sure that `myNode` has alpha < 1.0 if you want to apply fadeIn action.

Comment: This actually is what it was - it had nothing to do with the function I was using - my mistake was I was calling FADE IN on accident (when the monster was already set with an alpha of 1.0 haha how stupid I am). I had 'fadein' set for both warpout and warp-in)

Answer (score 0):

This function seems to be missing a return statement.  It would not compile so I presume that something is missing from your sample code.

```
func warpOutAnimation() -> SKAction
{
   SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(1.0)
}
```

Comment: ah just forgot to paste it here thanks. Updated the code.